# Coin Tosses Conditioning

Tags: probability

What is the expected number of tosses of fair coin to get $THH$?  Here's my approach:  Let $N := $ number of tosses to get $THH$.  Then by partitioning the sample space,
$$
E(N) = E(N; H) + E(N; T).
$$
If we get a $H$ on the first toss (with probability $\frac{1}{2}$) then we basically start over, so
$$
E(N; H) = \frac{1}{2}(E(N) + 1).
$$
If we get a $T$ on the first toss, partition further:
$$
E(N;T) = E(N;TT) + E(N;TH).
$$
If we get a $TT$ (with probability $\frac{1}{4}$) then we essentially start over from the $T$ state, so
$$
E(N;TT) = \frac{1}{4}(E(N;T) + 1).
$$
If we get a $TH$, partition one more time:
$$
E(N;TH) = E(N;THH) + E(N;THT).
$$
Obviously,
$$
E(N; THH) = \frac{1}{8}\cdot 3,
$$
while if we get a $THT$ we again start over from the $T$ state, giving
$$
E(N;THT) = \frac{1}{8}(E(N;T) + 2).
$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
E(N;T) & = E(N;TT) + E(N;TH) \\
& = \frac{1}{4}(E(N;T) + 1) + E(N;THH) + E(N;THT) \\
& = \frac{1}{4}(E(N;T) + 1) + \frac{1}{8}\cdot 3 + \frac{1}{8}(E(N;T) + 2) \\
& = \frac{3}{8}E(N;T) + \frac{7}{8},
\end{align*}
and so
$$
\boxed{E(N;T) = \frac{7}{5}}.
$$
This immediately seems wrong - it seems like I'm saying, starting from a $T$, it only takes 1.4 tosses to get $HH$ on average.  Certainly it should be larger than 2, so I believe there is a mistake in my logic here.  Just to finish my attempt at the problem, my answer would be
\begin{align*}
E(N) & = E(N; H) + E(N; T) \\
& = \frac{1}{2}(E(N) + 1) + \frac{7}{5},
\end{align*}
so $E(N) = \frac{19}{5}$, but the correct answer is $8$.

Comment: Consider Markov chain on all triplets of states.Stationary distribution is uniform hence every state has probability $\frac 1 8$. This means that average time to return ti THH starting at THH is $8$. But starting from scratch is equivalent to starting from THH, so expected time is $8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're losing track of how often you've multiplied by $\tfrac 12$.   
You need to keep the probabilities of the conditions separate from the conditional expectations.   Thus by using the Law of Total Probability we get:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(N) & = \tfrac 12 \mathsf E(N\mid H)+\tfrac 12 \mathsf E(N\mid T)
\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 12(\mathsf E(N)+1)+\tfrac 12 \mathsf E(N\mid T)
\\[2ex] \mathsf E(N) & = 1+\mathsf E(N\mid T) & \bigstar
\\[1ex] & = 1+\tfrac 12\mathsf E(N\mid TT)+\tfrac 12\mathsf E(N\mid TH)
\\[1ex] & = 1+\tfrac 12(1+\mathsf E(N\mid T))+\tfrac 12\mathsf E(N\mid TH)
\\[1ex] & = 1+\tfrac 12\mathsf E(N)+\tfrac 12\mathsf E(N\mid TH) & \textsf{because }(\star)
\\[2ex] \mathsf E(N) & = 2+\mathsf E(N\mid TH)
\\[1ex] & = 2+\tfrac 12 \mathsf E(N\mid THH)+\tfrac 12\mathsf E(N\mid THT)
\\[1ex] & = 2+\tfrac 32+\tfrac 12(2+\mathsf E(N\mid T))
\\[1ex] & = 4+\tfrac 12\mathsf E(N)& \textsf{because }(\star)
\\[2ex] \mathsf E(N) & = 8
\end{align}$$